# NSTableCellView with NSGridView

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nstablecellview

I try to use a NSGridView to Layout a NSTableCellView like this

```
class GridItemCV: NSTableCellView
{ var grid :  NSGridView? = nil

  let empty = NSGridCell.emptyContentView

  var tf = NSTextField()

  override init(frame frameRect: NSRect)
  { super .init(frame: frameRect)
    setup()
  }

  required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)
  { super .init(coder: decoder)
    setup()
  }

  func setup()
  { self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    grid = NSGridView( views: [
      [empty, empty],
      [empty, tf]
    ])
    grid?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addSubview(grid!)

    grid?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    grid?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    grid?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    grid?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  }
```

My problem.

The property textField, that should be connected by Interfacebuilder is not yet instantiated in the constructor. At what time can I access this property?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Building the NSGridView in

```
awakeFromNib()
```

I could access the property textField, wired up from Interfacebuilder